# uSD card accidentally wrong voltage

Tags: stm32, sd, esp32

(initially using STM32H745 w/ CubeIDE) uSD card was working, but was getting some fifo underrun issues? so I started switching rising/falling edge, and flow control and stuff. Now the card doesn't work at all in any laptop, with an ESP32 over SPI that it used to work with, all yield nothing. After switching everything back to default I'm getting back CRC errors on the STM32 on the attempt to find SCR to switch to 4 bit mode. But still no luck when I switch in the ESP32, I'm getting a failure to go to idle state. Sadly I don't have a great way to debug the ESP32, just print statements in user code.

I am worried that I may have accidentally run the STM32 code with the "transceiver" option, which switches the card down to 1.8v. Doesn't explain why it wasn't working before I started messing with things, but would explain it now. Is it possible that in switching to 1.8v, and still giving it 3.3v signals, I fried something? No pins are shorted to each other and the card doesn't get hot, but it sure doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: What does this transceiver option do exactly? Normally for overvolted inputs, I would have expected a short between Vdd and some other pins from the ESD diodes kicking and trying to clamp. See if Vdd measures <2K with any other pin.

Comment: @DKNguyen transceiver option has the code think I have a 3.3->1.8v translation layer and sends out a CMD11 (?) to switch over

Comment: It still runs on 3.3V though right? Or does the power supply change somewhere like inside maybe?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I tried looking up like "accidentally switched sd card 1.8v" and got a swarm of rpi posts, kind of frazzled so my google fu isn't up to snuff. And no pins have anything less than a few megaOhms to each other. My understanding is that 1.8v switches the transceiver circuitry in the uSD card for higher speed/lower voltage type thing, but I don't know what the protection on that is

Comment: I don't know either. If you set it to 1.8V logic levels, don't you need to send 1.8V logic signals to set it back to 3.3V? Or are the pins that set that different than the ones that are affected by the setting?

Comment: well it's a command, not a pin thing. I believe on reset it reverts, but I don't know. after all, its job is to not lose data after power off

Comment: Hmmm. You might want to find out if that is a volatile setting or not.

Comment: That's... Kind of what this question is, yeah. Is it fried or is it recoverable

Comment: If it's a standard protocol you might have to look up the SD card spec.